# How can I verify authenticity token when submitting form through ajax success?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a condition in which firstly the ajax request is triggered to fetch respective host url. In case the condition returned is true I want to submit the rails form. The form is submitted correctly but I get the error can't verify authenticity token.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var url, email;
      $("form#new_user").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        email = document.getElementById("user_email").value;
        $.ajax("/return_host", {
          type: "GET",
          data: {
            email: email
          },
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
          },
          success: function(data) {
            if(data['goto'] == true){
              host = data["host"];
              url = host + "/users/sign_in";
              $("form").attr("action", url);
              $("form").trigger('submit.rails');
            } else {
              location.reload();
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

How can I send authenticity token when triggering rails form through ajax success?

Comment: Can you try adding `headers:  {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))}` and removing the `beforeSend` key?  I've had that work before, but I'm not sure if that is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your form has a hidden input field named `authenticity_token` or not, for forms generated with rails helpers this field is included by default.

If not then this is what is causing error as rails expects a param called `authenticity_token` when you post a form.

You can add this on the fly in your success callback as shown below:

```
     success: function(data) {
        if(data['goto'] == true){
          host = data["host"];
          url = host + "/users/sign_in";
          var form = $("form");
          var authenticityToken = document.createElement("input");
          authenticityToken.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
          authenticityToken.setAttribute("name", "authenticity_token");
          authenticityToken.setAttribute("value", $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
          form.append(authenticityToken);
          form.attr("action", url);
          form.trigger('submit.rails');
        } else {
          location.reload();
        }
      }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Rails 5.1+ I'd recommend using `form_with` helper to handle the ajax request [https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with].

You'll still be able to hook into the success and error callbacks using code as I've shared below.

```

```
let form = document.getElementById('my_form')

form.addEventListener('ajax:error', (event) => {
  let form                  = event.target
  let [errors, status, xhr] = event.detail

  // DO SOMETHING
})

form.addEventListener('ajax:success', (event) => {
  let form = event.target

  // DO SOMETHING
})

form.addEventListener('ajax:before', (event) => {
  let form = event.target

  // DO SOMETHING
})
```

```

This way rails will handle the authenticity token/csrf yet you'll still be able to use Ajax - with option `data: { remote: true }` to ensure no page reload.

Hope this helps.